# NOT EQUAL operator != not working as expected in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have made a new column in my database table:

```
alter table TABLE add (COLUMN NUMBER(1));
```

Now I want to select all records where the value of column is not zero, either it’s some other number of empty (null)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN != 0;
```

And by default all columns have empty/null value as this column is recently added so it should return all records but doesn’t return any.

But if a change the value for this column of a record to `0` and run below query it works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = 0;
```

Please help I want to select all records where the value is not `0`.

Comment: NULL cannot be compared with equality operators, use IS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `NULL` values you have to explicitly give `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN <> 0 OR COLUMN IS NULL;
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NVL(COLUMN,1) <> 0
```

The Optimizer is going to do like in the first case even if you go with `NVL()`

Comment: You state "The Optimizer is going to do like in the first case even if you go with NVL()". Can you give a reference that documents this? You make me doubt, but I *think* this is not true.